# TimescaleDB Continuous Aggregation: How to store Continuous Aggregation Results

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

We're using the Continuous Aggregation to make some analysis from row data but i have some question about store logic. How TimescaleDB handle to store Continuous Aggregation result and normal Postgresql raw data table, i didn't find any result about that. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregated results for Continuous Aggregates are stored in a separate hypertable again. That said, you will have one hypertable per CAGG storing the resulting data.

The different components that make up a CAGG can be found in the documentation: https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/about-continuous-aggregates/#components-of-a-continuous-aggregate

I hope this helps.